# Security Groups Aws Mongodb EC2 Ami 2

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Im trying to host Mongodb on AWS EC2 Ami 2, I have commented out bindip and made bindipall to true, Aws Security Groups Setup im unable to figure out.
Mongodb uses 2717 port, Which type of connection should i be adding in security groups? All tcp protocol?

Comment: Would recommend using AWS DocumentDB with MongoDB driver. Using EC2 to host your MongoDBs is like shooting yourself on the foot in the long run. https://aws.amazon.com/documentdb/

Comment: Ive tried out documentdb but its kinda real complex, Aws charged me a lot whereas if i selfhost i'd be paying only for the ec2, Coming back to the question Please guide me with the security group protocol for 27017

Comment: Just open port `2717` protocol `TCP`.